# I don't know how to create this tree in R

Tags: r, tree

I would like to maximize revenue by applying the better campaign at each hour.

I would like to create a tree that would help me choose the better campaign.

At the data below there's a record with the revenue per campaign per hour.

Looking at the data, I may see that campaign A is better between hours 1-12, and that campaign B is better between hours 13-24.

How do I create in R the tree that would tell me that?

```
  hour campaign revenue
    1        A      23
    1        B      20
    2        A      21
    2        B      22
    3        A      23
    3        B      20
    4        A      21
    4        B      22
    5        A      23
    5        B      20
    6        A      21
    6        B      22
    7        A      20
    7        B      17
    8        A      18
    8        B      19
    9        A      20
    9        B      17
   10        A      18
   10        B      19
   11        A      20
   11        B      17
   12        A      19
   12        B      18
   13        A       8
   13        B       9
   14        A       6
   14        B      11
   15        A       9
   15        B       8
   16        A       6
   16        B      11
   17        A       9
   17        B       8
   18        A       6
   18        B      11
   19        A       3
   19        B       2
   20        A       3
   20        B       2
   21        A       0
   21        B       5
   22        A       3
   22        B       2
   23        A       3
   23        B       2
   24        A       0
   24        B       5
```

Comment: Could try something like `library(party) ; ct <- ctree(revenue ~. , df) ; plot(ct)`

Comment: Thanks @DavidArenburg. I know how to create trees in R. But How do I create the tree that I specified? My mission is to choose the better campaign, not to predict the revenue.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what kind of tree you are looking for exactly, but a linear model tree for `revenue` with regressor `campaign` and partitioning variable `hour` might be useful. Using `lmtree()` in package `partykit` you can fit a tree that starts out by fitting a linear model with two coefficients (intercept and campaign B effect) and then splits the data as long as there are significant instabilities in at least one of the coefficients:

```
library("partykit")
(tr <- lmtree(revenue ~ campaign | hour, data = d))
## Linear model tree
## 
## Model formula:
## revenue ~ campaign | hour
## 
## Fitted party:
## [1] root
## |   [2] hour <= 12: n = 24
## |       (Intercept)   campaignB 
## |         20.583333   -1.166667 
## |   [3] hour > 12: n = 24
## |       (Intercept)   campaignB 
## |          4.666667    1.666667 
## 
## Number of inner nodes:    1
## Number of terminal nodes: 2
## Number of parameters per node: 2
## Objective function (residual sum of squares): 341.1667
```

In this (presumably artificial) data, this selects a single split at 12 hours and then has two terminal nodes: one with a negative campaign B effect (i.e., A is better) and one with a positive campaign B effect (i.e., B is better). The resulting `plot(tr)` yields:

[image: lmtree visualization]

This also brings out that the split is also driven by the change in revenue level and not only by the differing campaign effects (which are fairly small).

The underlying tree algorithm is called "Model-Based Recursive Partitioning" (MOB) and is also applicable to models other than linear regression. See the references in the manual and vignette for more details.

Another algorithm that might potentially be interesting is the QUINT (qualitative interaction trees) by Dusseldorp & Van Mechelen, available in the `quint` package.

For convenient replication of the example above: The `d` data frame can be recreated by

```
d <- read.table(textConnection("hour campaign revenue
    1        A      23
    1        B      20
    2        A      21
    2        B      22
    3        A      23
    3        B      20
    4        A      21
    4        B      22
    5        A      23
    5        B      20
    6        A      21
    6        B      22
    7        A      20
    7        B      17
    8        A      18
    8        B      19
    9        A      20
    9        B      17
   10        A      18
   10        B      19
   11        A      20
   11        B      17
   12        A      19
   12        B      18
   13        A       8
   13        B       9
   14        A       6
   14        B      11
   15        A       9
   15        B       8
   16        A       6
   16        B      11
   17        A       9
   17        B       8
   18        A       6
   18        B      11
   19        A       3
   19        B       2
   20        A       3
   20        B       2
   21        A       0
   21        B       5
   22        A       3
   22        B       2
   23        A       3
   23        B       2
   24        A       0
   24        B       5"), header = TRUE)
```

Comment: Very interesting. I'm so comfortable with `party` so can't force myself to move on to this new package.

Comment: The user interfaces in `partykit` are very similar to those in `party` so that the transition should not be too hard. And the new `ctree` and `mob` code has many small additions and improvements and, most importantly, the whole underlying tree infrastructure is far more flexible and intelligible!

Comment: Thanks a lot @AchimZeileis for the detailed and very usefull answer. And thank you for developing the package (:

Comment: @AchimZeileis How does an lmtree decides what is a significant instability? Which parameters do I have for influencing the decision? I use minsize, but I can't figure out why I have only a small 2 node tree: I set minsize to 10000, and I get a single split to 2 nodes of 110000 cases and 70000 cases, and that's it, no more splits.

Comment: The idea is that a score-based parameter stability test is carried out (essentially an LM-type test). Details are described in the original publication in _Journal of Computational and Graphical Statistics_,  17(2), 492–514. http://dx.doi.org/10.1198/106186008X319331. See also the explanations and further references at http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/134143/splitting-criterion-in-model-based-recursive-partitioning/134965#134965.

Comment: As for the control parameters: The main control argument is `alpha`, the significance level where higher values lead to more liberal tests and thus potentially larger trees. The `minsize` parameter controls the minimum number of observations per node so that higher values permit less splits. You can also inspect the test results by calling `library("strucchange")` and then `sctest(mob_tree)` or `sctest(mob_tree, node = 2)` etc.

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this work?

```
## create a sequence of hours from column 1 of the data
hr <- as.numeric(unique(data[,1]))

## Set up vectors to hold the A and B campaign "best" hours
A.hours=NULL
B.hours=NULL

## start at the lowest hour 
i=1
while(i<=max(hr)) {
    ## create a subset of data from the current hour 
    sub.data <- data[matrix(which(data[,1]==hr[i])),]
    ## find the campaign with the highest revenue  
    best.camp <- sub.data[which(sub.data[,3]==max(sub.data[,3])),2]

    if(best.camp=="A") {
        A.hours <- c(A.hours,hr[i])
    }
    if(best.camp=="B") {
        B.hours <- c(B.hours,hr[i])
    }

    i=i+1
}
```

The code indicates that during the A.hours (hours: 1  3  5  7  9 11 12 15 17 19 20 22 23), campaign A is more profitable.

However, during B.hours (hours: 2  4  6  8 10 13 14 16 18 21 24), campaign B is more profitable.

Comment: Thanks @AlexMiller, but this is a data mining question. 
A tree is required, there's not enough data in order to make use of your solution. 
Running your code on my data results as follows: 

1-A
2-B
3-A
4-B
5-A
6-B
7-A
8-B
9-A
10-B
11-A
12-A
13-B
14-B
15-A
16-B
17-A
18-B
19-A
20-A
21-B
22-A
23-A
24-B

This is a useless arbitrary answer.
A tree would give a valuable answer:
Between the hours 1-12 campaign A is better.
Between the hours 13-24 campaign B is better.

Comment: Based on the data you provided, I believe the code I supplied gives the answer you're looking for.  I made a small edit to my original answer to save the hours corresponding to the most profitable campaign (A or B). You will notice that most of the time the more profitable campaign switches  hour to hour from A to B, however, this is not always the case.  For example,  for hours 19 and 20, campaign A is more profitable.  Let me know if this is not what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks again @AlexMiller, but as I wrote, I do need a tree. A tree is required in those cases when the result changes arbitrarily due to not enough data. The data that I created here manually represents arbitrary changes that make a calculation per hour meaningless, and also represents a clear advantage of A between 1-12 and of B between 13-24. This is a technical question regarding building a tree that is based on a special kind of a splitting criteria. Can someone tell me how do I create a tree with the specified special splitting criteria?